# Closed Loop control of a propeller

Tags: closed-loop

Hello I'm trying to control the velocity of the propeller with the pitch angle. I have a diagram from the factor cp over J and phi (see image: [Draw.io diagram](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=Regelung%20Propeller.xml#R7V1bb6M4FP41kWYeWmHuPE4zmV2NplK1s9LOPI1o4iRsKURA23R%2B%2FdpgA76QksTc0q2qKRhj4Fy%2Bc%2FGxZ2bMH%2Fd%2FJP5uexuvYDjTtdV%2BZnye6TrwXAP9wS2vpEX3tKJlkwQr0lY1fA9%2BQ9JIuz0FK5gyHbM4DrNgxzYu4yiCy4xp85MkfmG7reOQferO35AnalXD96UfQqHbP8Eq2xatru5U7X%2FCYLOlTwa2V1y595cPmyR%2BisjzZrqxzn%2BKy48%2BHYs8Id36q%2Fil1mQsZsY8ieOsOHrcz2GIiUvJVrzvl4ar5XsnMMra3GASTqXZK%2F12uEKkIKdxkm3jTRz54aJqvcm%2FD%2BIRNHS2zR5DdAjQIdwH2Y%2Fa8U%2Fc5dpCZ%2F%2FCLHslfPafshg1VWN%2Fi%2BMduUt8f0qo%2BClZkjc0TCISfrKBpJupF2347XlyIjmF8SPMklfUIYGhnwXPLKN9Ii%2Bbsl9FM3RAyCYnoU3GePbDJzLqrUDUDO4zllYJTIPf%2Fn3eAZNxFwdRlr%2BGdTOzPqMWPww2EWpYIlrABDU8wyQLkJB%2BIhceg9UqZ0jo38PwphS9eRzGSf5cKnwywlLW41HhfiZRK%2FJ2VIhEWhL1viIjtSYtGekOf3KtS7xep4ifPO3LB7ZiBxWOGjv%2BgpsQEZDnycs2yOD3nZ%2BL1QtCMpZBfroroGUd7LGwc2K%2FCf00JcdplsQPsEZ2Lf85JM8C1UXqkquOTTCKgik9f6mQCVAc29ZRiTaeI92GJZBTICSWut0RBIriCB5Fm%2FYSSe6yDY5mrkgzT0IyVwXF7Lcphu5ApgwT4VghFIlWcqi1ROkscXSRNqaENqYK2rgCba5OwEpsQdLCmICjgFIE2XUQhpxcSoW1WbY74IhEw2UKrkS%2FPYm03rxrnjSrRVdMoKp1EDKi1Sfs2WKa4i8NlpzvFaGH%2FiDfn59U3lezX9aIwYy%2FRRCt7m9RM%2Fumv1UjnyUhH2071XfY09dhNciwOLYU30PuqjvE%2FEAeN5DGDVQQQRjoBE%2FFtEQmj973pn4243u3lQX1vreoOHcnYFf%2FvncTGh3t6Vxp15rBSOyVfp5GKfXGbQmQDSnjh1CynfxLYk9bufzLsQkYnFsrGB914GTT6LDSrOVuCqpFJU6Jahkm0MerXKYY6s50E%2F9a83XiL2cOIvk8hOvsQ9US%2FUL%2FBGk2cz7nvzcIQ9Ffa55go%2FyxaMOn2xgNXd6fH9IhpDdaC8zkhYUbi7eYaMANwKARtyXzyKURd3fxs2dZA1KA%2BhiHKDCMLJW8eVuY%2BqGUcwGUolc5pZNInCajI%2B%2Bgn6RzLehYC8BI%2FCmLvsC1hvwxxreoNdzBJEAvh81e4YEQh4Ye%2F6w5N3zfZhoz%2Fokj%2Bie0bSyxGost3omRmssOw6en1LlClpi0OlE4NEE43hIM8J4Eg8uCCQjZVjLQjddG7Ue3mXG5qwYwu5Ic2xYFpYvo51BUozT6t2XRj9VSiNRH%2FzJPifi%2Fz36y2wbY101jdFOjTzrGCIZOIChJDqCokZH%2BK3CerqpNDxyIYAoOoosfcOA5%2F%2FoRxyC4i7bcfahdx1esBWI0%2BrJTQ4%2BhIg2jTaRhd%2BU92u6lwZMlgae2Nk45PDmyrL4ATyQUnw46UW9IBTrpGnVVRolOsrlvwkCsBMl9ggElT5eQ1AgoUiPohW%2F%2B%2FlUHMXS8XMX4FdMi84J5fxdky%2B1LED3AMIEbGD5Fm8lBmK0NmSxxnH4grLf8si1x0x1DNYQ1%2BN98aFbOr6h3jQFNrArKdfvr23TQkMqfEjQ0S06fPVHA3qEGDWU5ksNoyDpqGvHV%2BNRy69S0tUDfpZVJ5lOz2wX0JvEOfR8uC9NuERmQdEQIKOHyAU4Ogt0WEKxLc2dKIFimyBzhxlchpmtcxYCsRMyR0UxFvtERZ9dEO6awRqzk0QRqxBxZTHiBFUnH88SUqbXIBCVKLRYxXmCh3hEs6L8ozBXtz7SjcwqwddfWVe7atibvgeicDea%2BTs0h0NtMYLtd%2BQOuxJRNWm6psWbkVhtKbr2%2ByQtE8qaIFBk335W3fQnwexOO8DNiqKV2XS20yFjkqmZRfiv6KP%2B11oFYquag2uQcTWFJ1ls30CRxJSDFO5wcemtNoXc0xYQkVQglIbgHAGCIP6q1Ta4sbCA2K3%2FclIxUiaFDGCmvk3WPVbU9M7lfu0RxFByPolXVfwWkQDmQuiKQDjeD4nWS3a0X20zR1klY5A02B%2B%2B2KY45OZNxCjbVA0XlmTaPTZAbtE6SqVKTYJYKyOpktnbiyuBJZnw9eyhlABrohEeCWenZdByyYiezqb9VEw7nT%2FPaqG5Wy2uxWvpy0NA0hkPDMg3%2FvwfHqZpkseZwC%2FS8ThfDj00hdDCkQvS0nPRQ3m10%2FgHQJBWrQzoInVQETx%2B1pHwabk8foPUdeU6ZT8aA%2BiSbLL5Y%2B6Jxa6T6tS89xZ%2BM2FdCXZd80LcZUS%2Fh8ljFsuVzBV0U4GlNqyeiSa6aKOVTTWEyXfT1ygw0ilkAAHoKfcaoiX3VwvKayO8M1qCIR88Oaq70Ocrm%2Buh0lqTMdpJaTmX%2FfC3Xrj3HHpVeq10u2FvJOgCS7B5QP2vUpEGcU2TR2rUuitbF%2FN5lbS5p0cWwvazeAKBFemh8tcP87pKWIRKtq90lAWizVYHC0uGKRxOoHQbgXWwweT5PetxhEoB3ssXkMVzpv5y4BOyRbjJZAhvjRYC2hQ3DbDPp0PzTudtM2lZnm1CANruLjs%2FICgt0ZFa2swU6wJTFTV2a2ZJLUzCz0h26LhHSj%2BdKj4t0gCnWg16it3MEEwawq6aYOJn2egdgyuJ502tpidVP8pgH9mG4tKU6sgC8sypoYF7aBlWl3WZld7DyWGD2tEHFKCeLKWawLn03icGz1%2BVYZOFx63U5Djh8g%2B0c7M%2Fm9sW7%2BQihu6pFYMqKuCe7IKjUuXewIqhUsYtcEtSvMexmr%2FppFDh0hcpvzqtS1O0C1iR72E%2B6wkHp1vajrnCwO4mpplHhULqwfauiabRTxbNrHOiDlBU5NG7UN9Eih3Jb1Esscuht09EOlj%2BJ0Ws7lZbt6teBnrd3dY7fy%2B0d7mzJF5Z0WRuBTqv%2F9bfQq%2Br%2FVjYW%2FwE%3D)), but not a analytical formula.

J = v*60/(n*D*pi), v: wind velocity, n: rotational speed, D: diameter of the propeller.

I get a motor torque and a rotational speed as setpoint. I should control the propeller speed by changing the pitch angle phi.

My question is, how do I calculate the controller to control the rotational speed?

My first approach was to invert the formula "Propeller Momentenstrecke". So I get the image below, but this is only valid if the Time Tphi is so small, that in this timeinterval the rotational speed changes less. There is a problem, if the rotational speed is very slow, so the output of the 3rd block become very big.

Do anybody knows, how I can control this system, which approach do I have to use? Do anybody know some papers?

**edit:** I'm talking about a small aircraft with one propeller in front. The maximum speed of the motor is 2500rpm mechanical, its a permanent magnet synchrone machine with 6 pole pairs.

[image]

Comment: What types of controllers have you come across in your research?

Comment: Basically you need to increase pitch angle to slow down the prop velicity and vice versa, but you would probably be better asking on the Aviation stack.

Comment: add details on range of values, rpm, v, [limits]  etc

Comment: The link to Draw.io seems incorrect. I just get an error message from that site saying "Error loading file - No file selected". Please check & fix.

Comment: Your question is naive and poorly defined.  THey also use individual blade pitch control  on Wind turbines to reduce tower momentum fatigue and blade pitch torque due to resonance on each of 3 blades at 0.3Hz. Some readers think you are describing a helicopter.

Comment: Till yet I know the linear control calculation and some nonlinear system descriptions like Input-Output Linearization (Feedbacklinearization), slidingmode, backstepping. My problem is, I don't have an analytical expression for cp(phi,J)

Comment: "I'm trying to control the velocity of the propeller with the pitch angle." - why?

Comment: Wind has more speed above ground and thus prop torque varies with tri blade rotor position, which I assume this rookie question is based.

Answer (score -1):

### edited

1. Scrap your design and this question** A better question has specs with niputs, outputs and stability criteria ..not how to solve a block diagram...
2. ALWAYS define better specs FIRST.
3. What are your real goals?   **define each block**
4. When you discover new parameters, update your design spec.
   a) optimum thrust control at optimal efficiency? stability margin?
   b) what are the disturbances, what is the allowed error to be ignored?
   c) divide each goal into finer goals,
   d) have you completed your design spec.?  not yet?
   e) then start with defined transfer functions for each block with PID feedback where necessary.
   f) then solve the compensation feedback with Nyquist, Root Locus or Bode Methods.
   g) How fast does thrust (prop pitch) need to change? ( BW, error tolerance (overshoot, steady state)
   ( 10~90% slew rate and bandwidth are related f=0.35/t) in slew rate depends on environmental swings ( disturbances)  **What is your error spec?**
   h) What is your stability criteria? 
   i) Is there a deadzone for power applied to a gear ratio motor to control pitch?  **These should all be in your specs in block diagrams or transfer functions.**

   j) Do you start with  a transfer function of each block or a model **(from the shoulders of giants)**
   k) Synthesize it. Solve it using Control Theory methods that work. Bode, Nyquist, Root Locus etc...
   l)  then realize it?  build it, test it 
   m)  write a test plan (DVT), verify the specs. Write a simple DVT report ( 1 page per test with fig. photo and results)

You may end up PMDC Motor RPM/n poles with pitch control being some other planatary gear motor with some kV/RPM spec range and power spec and holding torque spec for a hybrid. or magnetic holding for a pure PM Stepper.
 - Thrust can be varied with Prop Pitch control with an efficiency curve with some actuator.

- Driver depends on cost, power, size, characteristics

Most efficient is a 3 phase PMDC with Field Oriented Control (FOC) aka Space Vector Control ( Re-search it)

- 8 equal shifted phases with PWM with sine and 6 of 8 logic vectors) (aka V/F RPM control)  voltage to the 3 phase motor using 6 vectors out a possible 8 to create a net sinusoidal force. But not the only solution.

end edit

I would expect inputs for Prop. Rotor position is connected to motor with a gear ratio and motor has multiphase voltage and current sensing.

RPM is best derived by rotation position sensor or EMF filter.  In order to have a faster system response time, it dictates the number of poles per Prop rotation are needed.

Velocity is then the derivative (D) of position so PID control constants should work well with other system constraints.

Motor Current indicates torque and expected changes in velocity by integration (I) but leads to more phase shift and overshoot but this can be used if demand power is less than supply and Prop angle can be increased with output PWM supply power to match demand.
... 
Generally if is best to control a system with 1st order feedback with high portional gain, since the system has integral inertia like internal compensation for an Op Amp is an integrator for gain control is stable with 1st order slope. But often Lead-lag phase filters are needed to optimize gain phase margin at unity loop gain.

## Since this question is beyond the scope of this forum

**[Research more here](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=closed%20loop%20control%20of%20propeller%20pitch%20wind%20power&btnG=)**

### **[MORE and MORE,](https://academic.microsoft.com/#/search?iq=@blade%20control%20@&q=blade%20control%20&filters=&from=0&sort=0)** refine your search with keywords

Comment: I can calculate the rotational speed from hall sensors, thats not the problem, the motor control works fine, but I need the closed loop control of the rotational speed by changing the pitch angle.

Comment: how it is sensed and controlled?  Linear? stepper?

Comment: The motor will be controlled via space vector modulation. Did it answear your question? There are 3 currentsensors to measure the current to control the motorcurrent. The motorcurrent will be controlled with a linear closed loop controller.

Comment: But when I don't get a analytical expression, I am not able to calculate the parameters for the PI controllers?

Comment: That is true . this is why we have Control Systems Theory so we can easily solve this.

Comment: Do you have some literature about this, how I can solve problems like this? To find the controller, it would be also possible to approximate the numerical values to get a analytical function. Is it a general way to do something like that?

Comment: Yes but, Your education is about learning how to learn.  Use special keywords to focus the answer or the whole question.

Answer (score -1):

It makes no sense to change the pitch angle within a rotation cycle, you would get a helicopter-like translational force on the rotor then. If you need exactly that, you better stick to a pure mechanical solution, a swashplate.

To avoid that, the pitch angle has to be controlled over at least one rotation cycle, for all practical purposes many more. Simply filter the rotational speed through a low-pass.

Comment: At 1 rev/second with possible step load at 50Hz , phase must be controlled at least 100 times per rev. in order to keep frequency synchronized or prevent over speed on prop tip. It depends on  J time constant

Comment: I had the impression the asker had a problem if the propeller speed is very slow – so her control loop would try to adjust the pitch angle within a cycle … which is extremely bad.

Comment: there may be a  large gear ratio, if for wind power

Comment: Yes, that gear ratio and limited speed of its drive would work as a low pass. But simulation does not and you may get the impression you had to leave out the low pass because the pitch  "crawls" into target position if the propeller isn't moving at all. One had to "bootstrap" the control loop for that corner case.

Comment: Pitch angle control bandwidth is  **much higher** than the blade frequency < 1 Hz in MW,GW wind turbines due to need for blade , tower and axial momentum stress reduction.  PID feedback with LQR, fuzzy logic etc and other means are used.  We're talking about megawatt generators with 3 blades that spin at < 1 Hz